# Keycloak error parsing SAML response in IdP initiated SSO

Tags: saml, keycloak

We're setting up SSO with Active Directory and Keycloak and trying to configure IdP initiated login. The Keycloak initiated login works, but the IdP initiated login does not, though the SAML responses for each of those is nearly identical (the only difference being `inResponseTo` on `<SubjectConfirmationData>` - this is present on the Keycloak initiated SAML response, but not on the IdP initiated SAML response). I've tried with Keycloak versions 4.3.0 and 4.4.0. The IdP settings can be seen [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLxtz.png) The Keycloak error and SAML responses are copied below.

Anyone have any ideas on this error?

When trying to log in with the IdP initiated flow, Keycloak returns this error:

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-62)
Uncaught server error: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException:
Could not process response from SAML identity provider.
```

The SAML response that does get parsed (Keycloak initiated request) is:

```xml
<samlp:Response Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
    Destination="https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/master/broker/saml/endpoint"
    ID="_e531b61c-6523-401c-b267-4a0525c80542" InResponseTo="ID_5d20a349-5af1-4bc8-973d-c7186d0685cc"
    IssueInstant="2018-09-26T18:15:25.260Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://greenhouse.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_0afd4f01-b9a0-4819-865c-e96319da773b" IssueInstant="2018-09-26T18:15:25.260Z"
        Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>http://greenhouse.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <Reference URI="#_0afd4f01-b9a0-4819-865c-e96319da773b">
                    <Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <DigestValue>RGUuFFUrcb3z+ncO3nUsg79tnTjPeB4O/87lPVdw1Dw=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>qP+/5mL5Tln8NKu/Rvz0fWjzMQ1W74UtpULH2OCF88hQtJCO0fGEYlI0kaSk7RSCdbDKx8aWvxkIS0Mi+0vMNGtgs5vWvKzzelm6GTbv7PfOByNd6hsyxBttiaowAsF2JreFJYWBXLr1XQTegA5tCmpmBgKlEVLKGyReF/UJj2/afzPmCkt8ACXq7Dx+Af70sHHHm8WNWJ45P0SHy5Yg/CnyhxC3rNh2MgCe3h9JEJNjNCbrchT9jx97Po80f6KABAaejYtTiUdTtzh7ufFDZ78wami5Z5kpE93X3zKj+CCM2wAWqCu0lQLYeP2KGS1ndK4roFU8iEd4rjuQszXXSQ==</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <Subject>
            <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">adminuser@example.com</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ID_5d20a349-5af1-4bc8-973d-c7186d0685cc"
                NotOnOrAfter="2018-09-26T18:20:25.260Z"
                Recipient="https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/master/broker/saml/endpoint"/></SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2018-09-26T18:15:25.260Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-09-26T19:15:25.260Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/master</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <AttributeValue>adminuser@example.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-09-26T18:08:16.444Z"
            SessionIndex="_0afd4f01-b9a0-4819-865c-e96319da773b">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:federation:authentication:windows</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

The SAML response that does not get parsed (IdP initiated) is:

```xml
<samlp:Response Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
    Destination="https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/master/broker/saml/endpoint"
    ID="_89868c3e-98a9-426a-8c49-53b128730584" IssueInstant="2018-09-25T21:22:34.653Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://greenhouse.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_6968f4ad-d97e-4f46-af2f-cbae662702f8" IssueInstant="2018-09-25T21:22:34.653Z"
        Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>http://greenhouse.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <Reference URI="#_6968f4ad-d97e-4f46-af2f-cbae662702f8">
                    <Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <DigestValue>FyYk5PDcetumqiefCgrNErVTBi52tGJ8kPGMTCByvUA=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>wC9OsDUzNQthY2pLD3hJNgwBceSBvKDcR6AiL2IsQ0A4iGY5tSF0p/YVWyDbe9rLIDcLctn8MQI9FuNCCqMU1QamTtvV1nV9SoPTmMdeC2NgeWnW9HAdg8Sv5tn5bD42E6NAG73RE2fUgWI57rm/+tlt8P3ROdLqXmEaVq5b0wfbqan+QroDxrjn/8oQdUx08mf1P24p37fFtlKWBDW3Oh/gN/0p9MYJIMJ0VjM9jWmoZ0GLz+Zf7NykEB8GzXQfiSWDCiTQfA287TilqpdK1Ni40tUBr1ZEDdqlR1o1gdu4P9rkSJqg1KnB4wwHq1F+cDZ9xVSPBhIBG43jO11D3A==</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDBjCCAe6gAwIBAgIQaERD4XNSb6FBU03xlUaYqzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/MT0wOwYDVQQDEzRBREZTIFNpZ25pbmcgLSBncmVlbmhvdXNlLndlc3R1czIuY2xvdWRhcHAuYXp1cmUuY29tMB4XDTE4MDkxNTE2NDc0M1oXDTE5MDkxNTE2NDc0M1owPzE9MDsGA1UEAxM0QURGUyBTaWduaW5nIC0gZ3JlZW5ob3VzZS53ZXN0dXMyLmNsb3VkYXBwLmF6dXJlLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAND/YMN2tASHJkCTQKfPW695H0Z0THDVTs6AL2y7NvxBgvwOQv5J9jr+QgQsNAr4QE0+jGZ7Z8TTySzySNn22LEGwOXiz4eW5clwtumHfghj1eN4rQDh+1AKxz0VYP4YXdjFemPrnfctlfEusn+/t2QzjrYzzMbC65AWAzPcCEe/udUZJ97ryzjnGx86SC9RR93d6C+HspRD2Sf+967FMG745czKI6paqQLzKe4iueRe+NEhFqLJgjfSQTwGRX8/dxL4KwNGtT0TxNQKiL6HhisyhwtLt3vDYTLBt4cmaalPJKJTFxwBBimb8L9og4IBMiDM5BHpOnQd68OlZLMCMi8CAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAAqxWIayXbZh1TKQgzGK7fIegHV+hjdHenUdXwzesWv3Wg6tUG/AdVTBn7uPNWV/ne7nCOBN//zwsP/iDD2/FhNDBbHHZz2bU70RDoLPB1TpZ0UkQ6WXILQp57kn4sTCpih5mJ8EwTU17cmcWJps2hpATHbgrHzjOWRqPqgqsXi7/yCYyv4MYQn3efY+HfIgAGc7Ez84ai7OEB2RmRNG93EoUAAR0OZfF+vPelAsdb2lkcb7bji5YKP1lK1mdfI4byFoWyFsnTR0x67EpKu8bOAlIhCaI6tRLT5xi5hMwgEjAplpEF0F2x/KBLPHl829/Y3U6Ze8dUik22imQFwwsEA==</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <Subject>
            <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">adminuser@example.com</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-09-25T21:27:34.653Z"
                Recipient="https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/master/broker/saml/endpoint"/></SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2018-09-25T21:22:34.653Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-09-25T22:22:34.653Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/master</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <AttributeValue>adminuser@example.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-09-25T20:20:26.139Z"
            SessionIndex="_6968f4ad-d97e-4f46-af2f-cbae662702f8">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:federation:authentication:windows</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! That's a properly elaborated question, I'm afraid I can't help with that, but hope someone can provide aid. I've added the [saml] tag anyway.

Comment: Did your problem resolve yet?